# Stock not reduce after paypal purchase in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

COD payment method reduce stock.But paypal payment method not reduce stock in woocommerce wordpress.
I am tested with paypal sendbox test account.
store have variation product type.

Comment: version of your woocommerce?

Comment: woocommerce 2.1.11 Wordpress 4.4.2

Comment: you need to update to latest version of woocommerce..

Comment: Ok thank you.I will update woocoomerce plugin.

Comment: I have customized woocommerce plugin.

Comment: what customisation you have made.Can you please let us know. I am also facing the same issue? thanks